# Different header's background-color on each categories

Tags: php, wordpress, header, background-color

I want to change a different background color of header for a category. The category is https://afdigitale.it/category/af-gaming. I use in functions.php this code but it does not work:

```js
<?php
if (is_category ('6933')) {?>
<style="background-color:black">
<?php
}
?>
```

Thx

Comment: Try passing the category slug to your `if` condition, like this: `if (is_category ('af-gaming')) {`.

Comment: where is that run? is that suppose to be an in-line style or a css sheet? the formatting with "<>" looks wrong

Comment: The formatting for the style tag you have is incorrect @cabrerahector  I've added my answer to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Dependent on what classes your theme is using, this work for me.  I hooked it into the class **site-content-contain** which was the main content container in the 2016 WordPress theme.  Add this code into your **functions.php** file for your theme.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_css_head' );

function add_css_head() {
    if ( is_category( 6933 ) ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">.site-content-contain{background-color:black;}</style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew it's ok, thanks for your reply. I have add this code: add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_css_head' );

function add_css_head() {
    if ( in_category('6933')) {?>
        <style type="text/css">.header-middle.herald-header-wraper.hidden-xs.hidden-sm {background-color:#000;}</style>
        <?php
    }
if ( in_category('6933')) {?>
        <style type="text/css">.header-top.hidden-xs.hidden-sm {background-color:#1f1e23;}</style>
<style type="text/css">.header-top a {color: #fff;}</style>
        <?php
    }
}

Comment: You don't need multiple <style> tags just the one.